# How to keep the same URL for both versions - mobile and desktop?

Tags: php, url, redirect, mobile

Is it possible to have the same URL for both the mobile and desktop versions? I don't mean a responsive site, but a completely separate mobile site with his own index.php, css and js files.

I would like the URL to remain unchanged and if the user enters from a mobile device to the website `example.com` it redirects to the appropriate index of a mobile version but the URL still remains `example.com` not `m.example.com`.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Search for `reverse proxy`.  But if you use different url structures, robots could get confused indexing.  Managing multiple code bases can become a headache.

Comment: Here is an nginx example of a conditional proxy pass. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-if-conditional-http_user_agent-requests/

Comment: I guess you are doing separate versions in order to speed up the loading times and get rid of unused code to keep the resources low. Keeping the same URL for different versions of the same content may look and sound like a good idea but SEO wise could lead to a disaster. I recommend you to have separate URLs and add canonical and alternate rel tags in your HTML head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes.

For example in Apache you can use mod_rewrite module and redirect the request to different `index.php` file depending on the client user agent.

Example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "..." [NC]
RewriteRule .* mobile.php [L]

RewriteRule .* desktop.php [L]
```

Also you can use one `index.php` as entry point, but you application can load different templates (theme) depending on the client user agent.

Comment: But how can I use mod_rewrite to redirect the request to a different `index.php` without changing the URL? I can use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "..." [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/m/ [L,R=302]` but it changes the URL.

Comment: @XardasLord I upodated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Personally i would recommend to search in apache context to archive your goal. Basicly you just want to redirect the user to different vhosts and you want a device detection to select the right vhost. Please correct me if im wrong.
I will link a short acticle [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-how-to-redirect-users-to-mobile-or-normal-web-site-based-on-device-using-mod_rewrite) where you can find a detailes tutorial to get this done.
Now you just need a good rewrite rule in your vhost-configuration to keep the domain unchanged. [Deep tutorial about rewriterules](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: Exactly, I want to redirect to a different index based on a user device detection without changing the URL. The code from the first article works fine, it redirects to a specific url when I enter from a mobile device. But it change the URL. So how should I use rewrite rule to keep the URL not changed? On mobile the address `www.example.com/contact` should be open on the mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use a front controller for both your sites.

You can replace the existing one with something like this:

```
<?php
$front_path = is_mobile() ? '/path/to/mobile/front.php' : '/path/to/default/front.php';

chdir(dirname($front_path));
require_once $front_path;

function is_mobile() {
    // Your logic here.  Probably sniffing headers.
}
```

This with a name-spaced folder structure:

```
$static_base_url = '/static/mobile';
```

Then a CSS url would look something like this:

```
$static_base_url . '/css/main.css'
```

If you already have your application adapted for use with a CDN then you may not need these changes.

Your assets may already be indexed by search engines, and restructuring may not be possible.  If so perhaps look at conditional reverse proxying.

(Rafts of existing rewrite rules and redirects may also complicate matters.)